# images on home page overlap on load

Tags: magento

Images on my home page overlap on load and also the it takes more time to load. Iam using magento 1.9.
I had used Litespeed_LiteMage magento extension to speed up my site load time but still there is no change.

I am still getting overlap images on page load.

How can I overcome this overlap issue

Answer (score 0):

Mostpropably it is an error in your CSS. But there can be a lot of reasons why images overlap... maybe you can post a link here?

Comment: I had also merge css and js from magento admin settings. But still the problem persisit

Comment: I am using magento banner slider on home page and that is causing the issue of image overlapping because inner pages are working fine and when I removed banner from home page image overlap issue does not occur. Is there any fix for this